# Any ideas for flexible serialization

Tags: .net, serialization, datacontract, serializable

I have some objects that serialized to output. Some properties of the object are heavy to calculate and take some time to do that. What I'm thinking about is how to specify the set of properties that user want to get and serialize only that set instead of all of them.

I already did some research and it's pretty clear how to serialize only desired properties for  objects that marked with [Serializable] attribute but in my case objects marked with [DataContract] and I still have some questions there.

Another problem is now to specify set of properties that should be serialized. Ideally it would be good to have something like XQuery to specify what exactly should be serialized.

So, for now it's more questions than answers... any ideas/thoughts//suggestions more than welcome!

Answer (score 1):

The following example creates a simple building with 3 floors and 4 rooms per floor. This is not an overly complex object graph, but I think it should get the idea across. The idea is that you can implement [System.Runtime.Serialization.ISerializable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.iserializable.aspx) to control the serialization process.

In this example, I only implemented the [System.Runtime.Serialization.ISerializable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.iserializable.aspx) for the Floors type. And in the Floors type I control how the Rooms list is serialized and de-serialized.

Without knowing more about the specific details of your type, specifically the properties which are heavy to calculate, I cannot speak to them specifically; however, I think by using the techniques provided by implementing [System.Runtime.Serialization.ISerializable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.iserializable.aspx) and controlling the serialization process, you will be able to achieve the results you are looking for.

Remember, you can add anything to the serialization stream, and you are not required to add everything in your class; however, you will want to at least make your class ‘correct’ after the de-serialization constructor runs. What you put into the serialization stream is up to you.

Be aware, however, this works for **Binary Serialization** only, not for **Xml Serialization**.

```
    Module Module1

    Sub Main()
        Dim floor1 As New Floor()
        floor1.Rooms.Add(New Rooms(101))
        floor1.Rooms.Add(New Rooms(102))
        floor1.Rooms.Add(New Rooms(103))
        floor1.Rooms.Add(New Rooms(104))

        Dim floor2 As New Floor()
        floor2.Rooms.Add(New Rooms(201))
        floor2.Rooms.Add(New Rooms(202))
        floor2.Rooms.Add(New Rooms(203))
        floor2.Rooms.Add(New Rooms(204))

        Dim floor3 As New Floor()
        floor3.Rooms.Add(New Rooms(301))
        floor3.Rooms.Add(New Rooms(302))
        floor3.Rooms.Add(New Rooms(303))
        floor3.Rooms.Add(New Rooms(304))

        Dim tower As New Building()
        tower.Floors.Add(floor1)
        tower.Floors.Add(floor2)
        tower.Floors.Add(floor3)

        Dim byteArray As Byte() = Serialized(tower)
        Dim backAgain As Building = DeSerialized(byteArray)
    End Sub

    Private Function Serialized(ByVal tower As Building) As Byte()
        Using ms As New System.IO.MemoryStream()
            Dim formatter As New Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter()
            formatter.Serialize(ms, tower)
            Return ms.GetBuffer()
        End Using
    End Function

    Private Function DeSerialized(ByVal byteArray As Byte()) As Building
        Using ms As New System.IO.MemoryStream(byteArray)
            Dim formatter As New Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter()
            ms.Position = 0
            Return DirectCast(formatter.Deserialize(ms), Building)
        End Using
    End Function
End Module

<Serializable()>
Public Class Building
    Public Sub New()
    End Sub

    Private _Floors As New List(Of Floor)
    Public ReadOnly Property Floors As List(Of Floor)
        Get
            Return _Floors
        End Get
    End Property
End Class

<Serializable()>
Public Class Floor
    Implements System.Runtime.Serialization.ISerializable

    Public Sub New()
    End Sub

    Public Sub New(ByVal info As Runtime.Serialization.SerializationInfo, ByVal context As Runtime.Serialization.StreamingContext)
        Dim counter As Integer = info.GetInt32("RoomCount")
        For index As Integer = 0 To counter - 1
            _Rooms.Add(DirectCast(info.GetValue(String.Format("Room{0}", index.ToString()), GetType(Rooms)), Rooms))
        Next
    End Sub

    Private _Rooms As New List(Of Rooms)
    Public ReadOnly Property Rooms As List(Of Rooms)
        Get
            Return _Rooms
        End Get
    End Property

    Public Sub GetObjectData(info As System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationInfo, context As System.Runtime.Serialization.StreamingContext) Implements System.Runtime.Serialization.ISerializable.GetObjectData
        info.AddValue("RoomCount", _Rooms.Count)
        For index As Integer = 0 To _Rooms.Count - 1
            info.AddValue(String.Format("Room{0}", index.ToString()), _Rooms(index))
        Next
    End Sub
End Class

<Serializable()>
Public Class Rooms
    Public Sub New()
    End Sub

    Public Sub New(ByVal roomNum As Integer)
        Me.New()
        _RoomNumber = roomNum
    End Sub

    Private _RoomNumber As Integer = 0
    Public Readonly Property RoomNumber As Integer
        Get
            Return _RoomNumber
        End Get
    End Property
End Class
```

Comment: Hi Randy, thanks for your response! I know about ISerializable interface and abilities that provides GetObjectData. But in my case my object marked with [DataContract] and I can't use ISerializable interface in this case. Now I'm looking on the IDataContractSurrogate interface and what it provides. Anyway, thanks for your response again!